# Correlations can be compared with the Comparing Correlations ('cocor') package or R - but what if one of the variables is ordinal?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, pearson-r, association-measure, fisher-transform

Let's say I want to compare the correlation of BMI and blood pressure in two independent groups and see, whether there is a difference between the correlations (whether the  correlation is stronger in one group than in another). This can be readily analysed with the 'cocor' package (and Fisher's z) in R.

But what if, instead of BMI, we were to compare the association of an ordinal variable - such as an academic grade (A, B, C, D, F) - and blood pressure in two independent groups to see whether there is a difference between the associations (whether the association is stronger in one group than in another)?

If I've understood correctly, we cannot compute the Pearson correlation coefficient if one (or more) of the variables is ordinal (not continuous), and thus, we cannot use the 'cocor' package to approach this question.